# localization on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localisation

I'm trying to translate civicrm into french but can't figure out how to do it.
I tried to put the l10n and sql folders in wp-content/plugins/civicrm/ and in wp-content/plugins/civicrm/languages. I also tried to put the fr_FR subfolder directly in these folder and directly the l10n/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/civicrm.mo file in the same places.
I also tried to chown these files and folders to www-data and to run a chmod 777 on them...
In the admin, only the default english appears, whatever what I try.
I checked the doc but I couldn't find the wordpress documentation (I just found for joomla and drupal).
Can you help please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Wordpress, make sure you have the following structure of files:

```
plugins/civicrm/civicrm/l10n
plugins/civicrm/civicrm/l10n/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/civicrm.mo
plugins/civicrm/civicrm/sql/civicrm_data_fr_FR.sql
etc
```

Reference documentation:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress

Comment: It worked thanks @bgm!
The problem was I put all the files at the root folder of civicrm and not in civicrm/civicrm... I think it's not very well explained in the doc...

Comment: The SQL files are required for the installation of CiviCRM. If you plan on using CiviCRM in another language, it's better to install directly in that language (otherwise you will have to manually fix a lot of configurations).

Comment: @bgm apologies if I've got that wrong.  The documentation doesn't make that clear.  I've removed my comment.