# I have everything done and still this red no go

Tags: wordpress, localisation

Language and Region Settings

CiviCRM has been translated to many languages, thanks to its community of translators. By selecting another language, the installer may be available in that language. The initial configuration of the basic data will also be set to that language (ex: individual prefixes, suffixes, activity types, etc.). Learn more about using CiviCRM in other languages.

I just don't get it. Im in FTP the files are all there. Is this saying to load them again??

Comment: Can you try what is suggested in this other question - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/6546/72 ?

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution, the issue was that I needed to add a file, named files, to the directory. This is not automatically populated in word press. It has plug-ins as a file where are the plug-in files are located. My eyes just didn't catch it at first that the problem was simple and it was asking for a directory that wasn't there.

Comment: Now I have everything in and working, however when I go in to add a membership type. it opens in a pop-up style box. The drop down menus in the box are populating their content behind the box. Some sort of glitch. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I'm glad that you found the solution to the problem. Your new question seems completely unrelated to the previous one. Probably a theming / css issue but if you need a better answer i suggest you open a new question and add a screenshot to it so anyone can understand the context.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm no tech, this is going to me layman's terms.

The issue fixed by going into FTP to the plugins file and adding a file named "files" and then dropping the civicrm folder into that file named files.